# Juntar dois projetos em um

Tags: c#, git, merge

Tenho dois projetos no Visual Studio, o Projeto 1 tem algumas coisas que o Projeto 2 não tem, e o Projeto 2 tem algumas coisas que o Projeto 1 não tem.

Portanto preciso fazer um merge dos dois e transformar em apenas 1.

Alguém sabe me dar uma dica da maneira mais fácil que posso fazer isso?

Obs.: Tenho o repositório local dos dois, e os dois também estão no Git, separados obviamente.

Desde Já agradeço.

Comment: Se ambos projetos tem os mesmos arquivos, uma ferramenta de merge deve te ajudar. Como WinMerge ou Kdiff3.

Comment: Não seria o caso de comitar as versões locais no repositório de origem?

Comment: Usei o WinMerge e resolvi aqui, algumas coisas foram manuais mesmo, mas o WinMerge me poupou um tempo bom. Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 1):

Não existe uma maneira automática de fazer isso, pois o resultado só depende do que você quer e uma ferramenta não saberia fazer essa escolha.

Um merge é o retorno de uma mudança de código quando você tem uma branch, ou seja, inicialmente você fez uma cópia do código. Neste caso você não tem uma branch, o projetos são diferentes, e você quer uní-los por uma conveniência qualquer, por exemplo, de arquitetura.

Então, manualmente, você irá escolher e mover os arquivos necessários. Isto se os seus projetos forem complementares.

Já no caso de terem sido projetos "espelho", por algum motivo, ou simplesmente, você está agora organizando e viu que algumas coisas podem ser melhores se você quer mover uma *function* ou *class*, a técnica para isso é *Refactoring*, ou [Refatoração de código](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refatora%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Essa técnica também se aplica de alguma maneira ao primeiro caso.

*Refactoring* é basicamente o processo de você arrumar o código ou melhorar ele, e para isso é bom que você tenha testes automatizados.

Ferramentas que tem ações do tipo: mover *class* para outro *namespace*, ou mover *class* para outro projeto, mover *function* de uma *class* para outra, ...:

- ReSharper, pago (é possível solicitar versão para estudante ou projeto Open Source) https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/
- CodeCracker, gratuíto (porém com poucas ações de refactoring) https://github.com/code-cracker

Para conhecer mais sobre o assunto, e outros importantes interligados, recomendo a leitura dos livros:

- [Refactoring, Martin Fowler](https://www.amazon.com.br/Refactoring-Improving-Existing-Addison-Wesley-Signature-ebook/dp/B07LCM8RG2/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=refactoring&qid=1558455790&s=digital-text&sr=1-1)
- [Working with legacy code, Michael Feathers](https://www.amazon.com.br/dp/B005OYHF0A/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1)

https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html

Answer (score 0):

Como você está no Visual Studio, tem um jeito fácil e rápido para isso.
Basta seguir o passo a passo a seguir:

1. Botão direito na solução
2. Adicionar
3. Projeto existente

Qualquer dúvida pode deixar aqui :)

Answer (score -1):

Mais fácil criar uma solução contendo os dois projetos. As chances de dar problema são menores.

Mas tirando isso, teria que ir arquivo a arquivo copiando, ou usar alguma aplicação que faça merge para arquivos que deveriam ser iguais.